# ng-if removes material design lite ripple effect

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design-lite

I have the following code
enter code here
**HTML:**

```
<nav class="mdl-navigation">
    <a ng-href="{{signInNavBar.Settings.Location}}" ng-class="styles.navBarElements">{{signInNavBar.Settings.Title}}</a>
    <a href="" onclick="location.replace(this.href)" ng-class="styles.navBarElements" ng-click="ButtonSignOut()">Sign Out</a>
    <div class="android-drawer-separator" ng-if="permissionLevels[currentUser.Role].ManagePermissions || permissionLevels[currentUser.Role].ManageUsers"></div>
    <a ng-href="{{signInNavBar.ManagePermissions.Location}}" ng-class="styles.navBarElements" ng-if="permissionLevels[currentUser.Role].ManagePermissions">{{signInNavBar.ManagePermissions.Title}}</a>
    <a ng-href="{{signInNavBar.ManageUsers.Location}}" ng-class="styles.navBarElements" ng-if="permissionLevels[currentUser.Role].ManageUsers">{{signInNavBar.ManageUsers.Title}}</a>
</nav>
```

**Firebase Database:**

```
{
  "permissionLevels" : {
    "Admin" : {
      "ManagePermissions" : true,
      "ManageUsers" : true
    },
    "Default" : {
      "ManagePermissions" : false,
      "ManageUsers" : false
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "12345" : {
      "Email" : "gm241709@gmail.com",
      "Name" : "Use Char",
      "Role" : "Admin",
      "uid" : "12345"
    }
  }
}
```

**AngularJS:**

```
$scope.styles: {navBarElements: "mdl-navigation__link mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect customNavElement"}
$scope.signInNavBar = {
    Settings: {Title: "Settings", Location: "settings.html"},
    ManageUsers: {Title: "Manage Users", Location: "users.html"},
    ManagePermissions: {Title: "Manage Roles", Location: "permission.html"}
};
$scope.currentUser = {
    // Retrived with firebase.auth().currentUser
    "Email" : "email@gmail.com",
    "Name" : "Name",
    "Role" : "Admin",
    "uid" : "12345"
};
$scope.permissionLevels = {
    // Data from database
    "Admin" : {
      "ManagePermissions" : true,
      "ManageUsers" : true
    },
    "Default" : {
      "ManagePermissions" : false,
      "ManageUsers" : false
    }
};
```

What I want this navbar to do is to display `ManageUsers` and `ManagePermissions` if the corresponding `permissionLevel` has that permission set to `true`. So if you are Admin it will display both of them and if you are Default it will not display any. What I have set up works perfectly andd displays according to their Role. The only issue is that the `ng-if` does not display the ripple effect on click. This only happens when `ng-if` is checking something that has been taken from firebase database, if I set it to a value that I have hard coded (such as `$scope.testVar = true`) it will work fine and the ripple effect works. This is not an issue with retrieving data as I have already checked. The other buttons (Settings and Sign Out) seem to work perfectly and they do not have `ng-if`. What have I done wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When elements are dynamically added to the DOM, they need to upgraded by MDL's `componentHandler` before functionality like the ripple effects are enabled.

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34740982/6680611) that explains the issue.

Basically, if you call `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();` after the information is retrieved from Firebase and the DOM is updated (that is, the `ng-if`s are evaluated) you should see the ripple effect enabled.